# Android USB Host

Tags: android, usb

I'm using the Android (4.1) USB Host API feature on a rooted device. I would like to know how to get the attached name "/dev/ttyUSBX" from the physical BUS and Device name. i.e /dev/bus/usb/001/006.

Comment: what you mean by "to get the /dev/ttyUSBX that is assigned from device /dev/bus/usb/00X/00X"?

Comment: It'd help us know what to tell you if you show us what you've got already.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the UsbDevice object, you can use [getDeviceName()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getDeviceName%28%29) to get the device file. According to the docs:

> Returns the name of the device. In the standard implementation, this
>   is the path of the device file for the device in the usbfs file
>   system.

Comment: This returns the BUS and Device name /dev/bus/usb/001/006. I need the relalationship to the /dev/ttyUSBX attached.